# Rsync to NFS directory via bastion with SSH as SSH user but write as www-data

Tags: wordpress, bash, ssh, rsync

I have this deployments architecture that deploy scalable WordPress using Amazon ECS containers. These are based from official WordPress image; The containers also mount an Amazon EFS file system on `/var/www/html/wp-content` mainly to host plugins and themes. The reason is because some plugins write files inside the `wp-content` directories, and I'd like the containers to have access to that files.

There is also bastion EC2 instance host so that I can access the EFS directory to make modifications and sync to locally.

[image]

The problem is I couldn't write the EFS directory without sudo-ing as `www-data`.

```
$ssh -i private_key.pem ubuntu@$BASTION_HOST

$touch /var/www/html/wp-content/test.txt
touch: cannot touch '/var/www/html/wp-content/test.txt': Permission denied

$sudo -u www-data bash # Access bash as www-data user

$touch /var/www/html/wp-content/test.txt
$ls -al /var/www/html/wp-content/test.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 Aug 12 01:08 /var/www/html/wp-content/test.txt
```

What I want to achieve is that I want to do rsync the plugin in my local development both to and from the `wp-content` directory.

I tried the command below

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -i private_key.pem" content/plugins ubuntu@$BASTION_HOST/var/www/html/wp-content
```

but it failed.

I also tried as `www-data`, just for sure.

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -i private_key.pem" content/plugins www-data@$BASTION_HOST:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

I tried rsync to other directory, though, and it works.

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -i private_key.pem" content/plugins www-data@$BASTION_HOST:/home/ubuntu/sync
```

I wanted to change the permission of the `/var/www/html/wp-content` in the bastion to `ubuntu`, but the last time I did it, the WordPress containers couldn't write to the NFS directory; so the safest way is to keep the permission intact.

What did I miss?

## Update 1

I tried adding `ubuntu` user into `www-data` in the bastion server.

```
$ sudo usermod -aG www-data ubuntu
$ cat /etc/group | grep www-data
www-data:x:33:ubuntu
$ touch /var/www/html/wp-content/test.txt
touch: cannot touch '/var/www/html/wp-content/test.txt': Permission denied
```

Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Great problem description.
Clearly there's a permissions issue, so I'll suggest the first thing to look at and assume you don't already have that covered.

Is the default `ubuntu` user a member of the `www-data` group?

Being a member of that group could give the required privilege levels.
To add the `ubuntu` user to the `www-data` group, allowing it/you to write to the mounted web directories while ssh'ed into the Bastion server:

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data ubuntu
```

To remove a user from a group:

```
sudo gpasswd -d ${USER} www-data
```

You'll have to test whether the ssh server on the bastion host will allow you to, say `rsync` files into the mounted web directories from your local development host. That might be a configuration issue in the bastions `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.. not sure, haven't tried, but one to look at next if necessary. Good luck.

Comment: Stil doesnt work :( I added `ubuntu` to `www-data` still cannot write.

Comment: I should also have mentioned that in order for the new group permissions to take effect, the bastion host might need to be rebooted.

Comment: too bad still not working.

Comment: ...  Sorry, we tried. You should be able to reverse what we did if necessary. Love your aws architecture, so hope you get a solution.